# simple $http.get request with params

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make following http request using angularjs `$http` service

```
$http.get('http://myserver:8080/login?', {
            params:  {username: "John", password: "Doe" },
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}
        }).then(function(response) {
            alert('success');
            alert(response);
            }, function(x) {
              alert('err');
            });
        };
```

my server is up and runing and I'm getting following firebug console error
[image]

So what I'm doing wrong here in sending http request?

Comment: Can you check the Request generated (via browser developer tools) ?

Comment: http://myserver:8080/login? i think your problem is here. Use relative path and remove "?"

Comment: Slightly unrelated but you should send login request as POST. GET parameters are always send in clear text over the network where POST parameters are encrypted if you're using HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for send GET request using $http.get with params

```
$http.get('api/anyApi/get', { params: {name:name}})
```

As you see, you do not need absolute path and ? param to use.

Also, as jfadich  mentioned - do not use GET for such requests.

Comment: please can you extend this with post example then, and with ?login as part of expected backend

Comment: My front part:

return $http.get('api/anyApi/login', {params: {username: "John", password: "Doe" }, headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}});